# Adding paragraph inside table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aem

In this case when we type some text in table cell it's just simple text like:

```
<td>some text</td>
```

But if I press enter, to break the text, first and next line gets `<p>`. For example:

```
<td>
<p>some text</p>
<p>second text after break</p>
</td>
```

What I want to get is wraping text in `<p>` since begining, when I start typing. So result is:

```
<td><p>some text</p></td>
```

Any ideas? Below piece of code for this part.

```
updateTableCells: function(richText) {
        var that = this,
            tdEl = richText.querySelectorAll('td');

        [].forEach.call(tdEl, function(td) {
            if (!td.children.length) {
                that.applyParagraph(td);
            }
        });
    },

    applyParagraph: function(element) {
        var newPar = document.createElement('p');

        newPar.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.appendChild(newPar);
    },

    parseRichTextContent: function(richText) {
        var par = richText.querySelectorAll('p'),
            orderedLists = richText.querySelectorAll('ol'),
            unorderedLists = richText.querySelectorAll('ul');

        [].forEach.call(par, function (paragraph) {
            if (paragraph.classList.length) {
                paragraph.classList.add('class-par16');
            }
        });

        [].forEach.call(orderedLists, function(ol) {
            ol.classList.add('listwall');
        });

        [].forEach.call(unorderedLists, function(ul) {
            ul.classList.add('ulistwall');
        });
    },
```

Comment: seems you are using a rich text editor plugin to update the <td >values. It would be better to add a fiddle to make your question more clear

Answer (score -1):

your question is not clear but dont use `<p></p>` try this.

```
<td>some text <br> second text after break</td>
```

- also if the sentence inside td is short then write `&nbsp;` instead of space to maintain the spacing

hope it will be helpful for you :) good luck